# Background for-loop only cycles once

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, for

I have the following setup:

```
x=0
y=1
z=2

task0(){
   for file in "${files_array[$x]}"
   do
      sed -i "$var" $file
      x=$((x+3))
   done
}

task1(){
   for file in "${files_array[$y]}"
   do
      sed -i "$var" $file
      y=$((y+3))
   done
}

task2(){
   for file in "${files_array[$z]}"
   do
      sed -i "$var" $file
      z=$((z+3))
   done
}

task0 &
task1 &
task2 &
```

The functions task0, task1 and task2 get executed in the background but every loop only cycles once. I need it to loop until the end of $files_array[].
$files_array[] is well populated and the function reads it correctly.
Where is my mistake?

Thanks and regards,
Jan

Comment: if you're looking for processing the entries in the array in parallel, you might want to look into GNU parallel and/or `xargs -P` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinary `for` loop iterates over a static unchanging list of items.  In each of your three loops, that list consists of exactly one item.

For example, in `task0`, you loop over the single element `$x` from the list `file_array`.

Instead, you may want to use `while` loops:

```bsh
task0 () {
    X=${#file_array[@]}

    while [ "$x" -lt "$X" ]; do
        sed -i -e "$var" "${file_array[$x]}"
        x=$(( x + 3 ))
    done
}
```

or an *arithmetic `for` loop*:

```bsh
task0 () {
    X=${#file_array[@]}

    for (( i=x; i < X; i+=3 )); do
        sed -i -e "$var" "${file_array[$i]}"
    done
}
```

These loops assume that the array `file_array` has consecutive indexes, which an array typically has unless you made an effort to remove elements or set elements out of order.

You may also use the file list like this, which voids issues with sparse indexes:

```bsh
task0 () {
    set -- "${file_array[@]}"
    shift "$x"

    while true; do
        sed -i -e "$var" "$1"
        shift 3 || break
    done
}
```

This sets the positional parameters to the file list. Then shifts off 0, 1, or 3 of the items depending on what `$x` is.  We then loop until we can't shift off three items from the list, and in each iteration we use the first item in our operation.

Note that you can use `task0` for all three of your background jobs:

```bsh
x=0; task0 &
x=1; task0 &
x=2; task0 &
wait
```